# How is kexec_load used?

Tags: linux, system-calls

Looking at the manual page for the system call `kexec_load`, I didn't see any obvious way to use it.

There is no argument for a kernel file, an initial RAM disk, or a command line string.

`kexec_file_load` has parameters for file descriptors of files representing the kernel and there is a parameter for initial RAM disk as well for the command line; but I am more interested in how the first one is used.

Comment: You can take a look into the kexec-tools source code.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend the source code, you have a good overview if you use git:

```
git log --oneline  | grep kexec_load
```

[image]

of which this commit looks very promising:

```
git show 6b27aef09fea
```

[image]

If you don't have it cloned by now, here is the GIT repository:

> git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git